# What WYISWYG/GUI eBook editor do you reccomend?

Tags: text-editor, gui, ebooks, books, epub

I am looking for a WYSIWYG/GUI eBook editor that has robust functionality beyond that of Calibre or Sigil.
I am speaking of the ability to edit many of the HTML elements via GUI without touching a line of code, adding interactivity (forms, quizzes) and complete formatting control.

I have found software such as Jutoh and Kotobee (even Kitaboo)? Are they comparable? Any other eBook editing tools that provide robust editing features from a GUI? This is not to exclude the ability of HTML/CSS editing, but I am looking for something that could allow feature rich eBook editing/creation without needing to code those sorts of elements.

Answer (score 1):

I have experience with Kotobee Author and I can tell you that it is what you're looking for. Kitaboo as well I think but I haven't used it much. Only Kotobee. the thing is Kotobee now offers widgets (they call it mini-apps) and it gets the job done for many of the features I needed without needing to code anything. So I definitely recommend checking it out.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use [Adobe InDesign](https://www.adobe.com/products/indesign.html). This offer you the possibility to visually create ebooks, (with forms and so on). But you can't edit already created ebooks. Also this product can cost you 21 USD/mo. Of course you have trial, probably student license.

P.S. No affiliate with Adobe

Comment: I looked at that but it doesn't appear to be a viable solution as it doesn't export out to ePub well nor can you edit them as you mentioned

Comment: about export to epub please check this page: https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/export-content-epub-cc.html

Comment: Didn't say it didn't export, said it doesn't very well. I.e I don't think InDesign is really intended to create digital content such as eBooks